# Android Leanback - How to add DetailsOverviewRow action icon

Tags: java, android, television, leanback

I need to add action button icons like on this example. How can I do this?
 Action obj have constructor, in which I can pass Drawable :

```
buttonsAdapter.add(new Action(1,
                getString(R.string.my_func), null, getDrawable(R.drawable.my_res)));
```

But `DetailsOverviewRow` ignores it. It displays buttons without images, only with action name.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the android.support.v17.leanback.widget.ActionPresenterSelector class. If you doesn't set the second label to the action, presenter just ignore icon. If you want to create action with only the first label then just create your own presenter for the actions and provide it to the actions adapter.